# Use alias and carry it on

Tags: alias, bashrc

Let's say I have this alias in my `.bashrc`

```
alias somedir="cd /var/www/site"
```

how can I use `somedir` in say ... a `cd` command?

e.g.

```
cd somedir/app/
```

doing this currently returns:

> -bash: cd: somedir/app: No such file or directory

Is it even possible to use an alias this way?

Comment: Even if aliases were expanded in operand positions this wouldn't do what you want, you'd end up with `cd cd /var/www/site/app` (note the double `cd`). Why not just use a variable?

Comment: `export SOMEDIR="/var/www/site"; cd "$SOMEDIR/app"`

Comment: @Fox ah of course, can't believe I missed that ... could I add it to the alias, e.g. `somedir/app`? (tried: answer no xD)

Comment: @RoVo I suppose that makes sense, create it as a var and then can use within the cd - ty :)

Comment: Also look up cdable vars and autocd in the bash manual (not sure if they can be combined, but one of them maybe useful)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `bash` shell has a `CDPATH` shell variable that helps you do this without an alias:

```
 $ CDPATH=".:/var/www/site"
 $ cd app
 /var/www/site/app
```

If there's a subdirectory of `app` called `doc`:

```
 $ cd app/doc
 /var/www/site/app/doc
```

With a `CDPATH` value of `.:/var/www/site`, the `cd` command will first look in the current directory for the directory path given on the command line, and if none is found it will look under `/var/www/site`.

From the `bash` manual:

> `CDPATH`
>
> The search path for the `cd` command.  This is a colon-separated
>                 list of directories in which the shell looks for destination
>                 directories specified by the `cd` command.  A sample value is
>                 `".:~:/usr"`.

Note that `CDPATH` should not be exported as you usually do not want this variable to affect `bash` scripts that you run from your interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a [handy Bash reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) (emphasis mine):

> A Bash alias is essentially nothing more than a keyboard shortcut, an abbreviation, a means of avoiding typing a long command sequence. ... It would be nice if aliases could assume some of the functionality of the C preprocessor, such as macro expansion, but unfortunately Bash does not expand arguments within the alias body. Moreover, a script fails to expand an alias itself within "compound constructs," such as if/then statements, loops, and functions. An added limitation is that an alias will not expand recursively. **Almost invariably, whatever we would like an alias to do could be accomplished much more effectively with a function.**

Notwithstanding your special case of `CDPATH`, [as Kusalananda answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477007/50240), an equivalent function might look like:

```
somedir() {
    cd /var/www/site/"${1:-}"
}
```

Now you've got:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ somedir
$ pwd
/var/www/site
$ somedir app
$ pwd
/var/www/site/app
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases don't work that way, but you could use a variable instead:

```
somedir="/var/www/site"
cd "$somedir/app"
```

<sub>With due credit to [Fox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476972/use-alias-and-carry-it-on/477046#comment871711_476972) and [RoVo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476972/use-alias-and-carry-it-on/477046#comment871712_476972) for suggesting this in the comments</sub>

---

And if you want to save a few keystrokes, you could set up an alias:

```
alias somedir='cd "$somedir"'
```

Or if you enable `autocd`, you can `cd` by just giving the variable like a command:

```
~$ shopt -s autocd
~$ "$somedir"
/var/www/site$
```